# How do I use view correctly or redirect table name to second name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, view, tablename

I am programming in `C#` and using a `MSSQL Server` for my databases. After years I got now the problem, that I realized my table name is not so good.

For example:

Old: DB_Orders

New: DB_CS_Orders
(CS = Computer Science Department)

I am basically creating new Tables with the same columns for different departments. (To separate them clean and use different ID/number ranges. (And main purpose that I know in my program dynamically from which department I need to SELECT ... example string TablenamePosition = MainTablename+"Position")).

Usually the tables don't exist and I can create new ones, but now I got some old ones which I want to rename after that new pattern and can't do that since the program is running 24/7. What I did to prevent it, I created views called like the new pattern and start programming like that.

Now the issue I got the views they do not refresh after I alter the main table(Add/Remove Column), even if I use `*` on the view. Is there better way to redirect just the table name?

Comment: Don't do this, creating a system that *requires* dynamic SQL to refer to the right object is *always* going to be a nightmare to work with. Add a column to your table to denote the department.

Comment: You should generally NOT be changing your schema. And when you do, you need to perform a proper impact analysis rather than just assume such changes will magically percolate throughout your codebase. And you should get OUT of the habit of using "select *" anyways.

Comment: I am using also the tables for number generation (ID/primary key) for the departments (since its required) and also to separate access from the beginning. I cant undone it, and see no reason why if would did that from the very beginning.

Comment: This should be a single table with a `Department` column. You can separate access using row-level security if you really have to

Comment: @SMor i know that changing needs also change in code which will be needed. But if it's done, i got no problems at all after that. (And if i keep going like that)

Comment: @Charlieface Does this work with differnt sql users? I should mention when i started programming and creating these tables i was noob and my boss didnt question it how he nammed things.

Comment: Also, you are misunderstanding what `SELECT *` does in a `VIEW`. This isn't read as "return all columns from the table at run time", but rather "add all columns that *currently* exist in the dataset to the `VIEW`". If a new column is added to a table that is reference with a `SELECT *` in a `VIEW`, the `VIEW` *will not* expose that new column. A `VIEW` is compiled when you create it, *not* when you reference it. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06c5cff30e42a44fd1d5646ad01b6c69)

Comment: @Charlieface another reason was that i didnt wanted be the tables to be big (since i had issues with many rows for file-permission table), and smaller reason was that i dont delete/alter something out of accident.

Comment: *"and smaller reason was that i dont delete/alter something out of accident"* That has nothing to do with the problem here; you can "accidentally" delete rows in a database regardless of if it's designed well or not, or if the table is big or small. The only way to avoid "accidentally" deleting rows is to ensure you check your queries *before* you run them and have *good* recover processes in place. In truth, I could see the likelihood of deleting the wrong rows being higher if you have to mess around with dynamic SQL to reference the right object(s).

Comment: @Larnu i know that now after i deleted a test-column and the program crashed after while since it asked it after the table. Thats why i am asking about a better way without changing to much. (Since i could not find anything clever and would expect from Microsoft some feature like that)

Comment: @Larnu i should say more my beginning problem since i was unsure what i could break as beginner. And yes i got my backups so dont worry and if i test something out i got my test-database.  The dynamic sql is not so much a problem as you think, since it handled from my programm in the very beginning. If i would switch my job to new company i would do it differently like you all said.  (But i got no time since i am alone and to much source code to change)

Comment: Right now what i am doing to prevent it, i use `sp_refreshview` on the table which has `*` , after i edited it. (But i kinda want it automatically on all views so i dont forget it and my programm crash's after while)

Comment: *"But i kinda want it automatically on all views so i dont forget it and my programm crash's after while"* No, it is by design that this doesn't happen. Stop using `SELECT *` in your `VIEW`s and when/if you update your table's definition update the objects that reference too. Doing this should be part of your deployment script.

Comment: @Larnu It's small company, there no script or rules. I dont want be rude but you sound like my friend who works only in big company where everything has his order/rule. If you are 1-man devolper you are cutting stuff like that, but my inner self still wish it to be like that. If i would do that for each little thing without the power of team, i would work 24/7 overtime and i dont get overtime paid. Please help me to improve without changing everything i worked so far. I just searching a way to refresh views without dropping/manually refresh them.

Comment: *"I don't want be rude but you sound like my friend who works only in big company where everything has his order/rule"* If 90 people is a "big company" then sure; I would call that small. But big or small, you should be creating deployment scripts. If you're the only person developing that's actually far easier as you don't need the same management on your source control system to merge the changes from multiple users; there is only one user: you.

Comment: *"I just searching a way to refresh views without dropping/manually refresh them."* Again, there is no such (magic) feature. *You* need to update the referencing views as part of your deployment. This is why change management is important, regardless of the size of the company, big or small. Being a "one man band" isn't an excuse for not having change management in place, when it's actually one of the easiest places to implement it as there's only one person making the changes (so they are easy to keep track of).

Comment: @Larnu Then thanks for your effort, i did not found something like that and sorry for repeating i guess i misunderstood you there. I guess i need to wait then and delete views and just rename the main table. (And keep going like that since i wont change over 100k of code). I kinda expected this "magic" from a microsoft product since it was so simple.

Comment: Lookup synonyms - you can create a synonym to reference any object by a different name.  This would allow you to at least use your new naming scheme.  With that said - you really need to consider what everyone else has stated.  The design is wrong and almost certainly susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Jeff Could you explain how why it is risky against attacks?

Comment: @RekeUnhs - if you are using dynamic SQL to concatenate strings to be executed, then you are going to be susceptible to an injection attack.  If you need further information - lookup SQL injection, there are plenty of articles about the issue.